# Python Socket: WinError 10022

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, pickle, recvfrom

Some years ago, I programmed a chat with Python 3 und everything worked fine on Windows and Mac, till now. This function is executed in another script:

```
import socket
import pickle

def get(sock):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    data = pickle.loads(data)           #to convert data back to a dictionary
    return data, addr
```

On Mac this still works fine. But Windows throws out an Error:

```
File "C:\Users\...\network.py", line 15, in get
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

What's the problem?

EDIT:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

Comment: How is `sock` defined?

Comment: sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to bind to the socket before calling `sock.recvfrom(1024)`.

```
sock.bind((YOUR_IP, PORT))
```